# Vim macro with ^M doesn't work

Tags: ms-access, vim

I wanted to save the following command to my _vimrc file with set (on gvim for windows), to easily add line breaks to access SQL when Access removes them:

`:/SELECT/,/FROM/s/, /,^M/g`

Entering this normally, it does as expected, but as a macro, it doesn't work and I end up with just `/g` leftover.

How can I change this to use it as a macro?

Comment: Try adding a backslash before the ^M.

Comment: Adding a backslash produces the same result \r worked, see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be using `\r` instead of `^M`